# Getting randomly "unable to unlink old '<file>' (Permission denied)" after a git pull within a Vagrant box

Tags: git, macos, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm working in a Vagrant box pre-packaged with [Homestead 5.0](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead) and sometimes after a `git pull` or `git checkout`, I get

```
unable to unlink old '<file>' (Permission denied)
```

After rebooting my box, I can pull or checkout normally. I've also tried to `git pull` locally and it worked perfectly.

**Setup:**

- Mac OS Sierra
- Virtual Box 5.1.14
- Vagrant 1.9.1
- Homestead 5.0

Anyone with this problem ?

Answer (score 12):

It looks like it's a bug with macOS (*possibly* El Capitan but confirmed on Sierra) and/or NFS.

See these Vagrant issues:

- [NFS permission problem on MacOS Sierra](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8061)
- [Problem with NFS Shared Folder Permissions on Mac OS X (El Capitan)](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6360)

Most people found that it seems to be related to a **filesystem caching issue**.

## Solution High Sierra (2017-11-21)

Upgrade to **High Sierra 10.13.2 Beta 2** as [confirmed by JF Bibeau](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8061#issuecomment-343681244).

> Upgraded to High Sierra 10.13.2 Beta 2, removed my cronjob that would periodically do an `ls -laR` as a workaround, [...]
>
> I'm happy to report I haven't seen this in almost 2 weeks of using High Sierra. It's completely fixed!

*Note that a new, but different, problem seem to have arised on High Sierra related to [incorrect listing of files on the guest machine](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8788).*

---

## Possible workarounds

If upgrading to High Sierra is not possible, here's a couple workarounds.

### Update Vagrant and Virtualbox

If possible, update both, though some people mentioned downgrading helped.

### Recursive listing on the host (Easy workaround)

Running the following **on the host** refreshes the filesystem cache:

```
ls -alR [synced_directory] > /dev/null
```

or opening the **Get info** menu of the synced directory seem to work temporarily.

Some people made **a cron job to do that every 5 minutes** so they never encounter the problem even if it's not a definitive solution.

[Someone pointed out](https://github.com/docksal/docksal/issues/265#issuecomment-311113917) that running **a recusive listing** of only the directory had the same effect and **was faster**.

```
find [synced_directory] -type d  > /dev/null
```

### Disabling NFS lookupcache

A [comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8061#issuecomment-265449569) in the issue mentioned:

> Disabling NFS lookupcache seems to work, but the performance is
>   unbearable.

### Change permissions of synced directory

On the host machine, give read and write access to **Everyone**. It also seems to work temporarily, probably for the same caching reason the opening the **Get info** menu works.

### Not using NFS

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./host", "/vagrant-dir", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]
```

But this has a huge performance downside.

### Using [vagrant-sshfs](https://github.com/dustymabe/vagrant-sshfs)

This is a vagrant plugin which allows mounting directories with SSHFS. Though from the drawbacks listed on the repo itself:

> Performance is worse than an implementation like NFS

### Downgrade to El Capitan

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580942/getting-randomly-unable-to-unlink-old-file-permission-denied-after-a-git/43741419#comment79564911_43741419) [people](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8061#issuecomment-292697993) mentioned that they were not having this specific "unlink" problem on El Capitan. So downgrading would be a *last resort* solution to avoid dealing with it.

---

Some registered Apple developers have reported the problem on [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com/) ([#28927426](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8061#issuecomment-271034896) and [#33043401](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8061#issuecomment-311824409)) but the information is private.

[Apple responded](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8061#issuecomment-338036074) and closed the original bug report, saying:

> The issue reported in this bug report is fixed but the High Sierra issue is specific to APFS and not the same issue. Please file a new nug (sic) for that issue. Thank you. We are now closing this bug report.

Comment: FWIW I do not believe El Capitan has this issue. I specifically downgraded to El Cap from Sierra and haven't had the issue since (approx > 1 month) - we use Vagrant extensively with NFS.

Comment: @sceo reformulated the initial diagnosis and added the downgrade as a solution.